# Tiling/Approximating a 3d surface with identical polygons

Tags: graphics, 3d, computational-geometry, mesh, triangulation

I'm not really sure if this fits in here or better in a scientific computer science or math forum but since I'm searching for a concrete algorithm...

I have a 3d model which is somehow defined either by a mesh or as an algebraic variety and i want to remesh/approximate this thing just using a fixed chosen type of congruent tiles, e.g. isoscele triangles with certain ratio of sides length to the base length. Is there a algorithm for that or does anyone know the right name for the problem? I found some algorithms that come close to what I need, but they all mesh via some tolerance in the length and different sizes of the tiles.

Comment: You can't approximate the sphere arbitrarily well with equilateral triangles. The same applies to any other tiles. Reason: angle defect around each vertex.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988257/non-linear-icosphere/12988743#12988743

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can, when i let the shrink the triangles arbitrarily.

Comment: Then we're not talking about congruence, and it's still impossible.

Comment: Care for a proof in the more general case where only similarity needs to be preserved for triangular tiles of any class?

Comment: An interesting case is when you allow an infinite number of tiles and you choose their shape after you know the desired approximation level. Even then, I'm sure there's no solution.

Comment: I think you are somehow misunderstanding me. The resulting mesh doesn't even have to be convex or whatever. I could prove that i can receive such a mesh for the sphere: Tile the 3d-space with tetrahedrons, consider those which are completely inside the unit sphere, then the surface of them would fit my needs (whereas not in the best way) if I chose a small enough side length.

Comment: If you don't care about the surface normals, then use any 3D tiling. The cubic honeycomb works pretty well.

Comment: To generate an isosurface up to a limited resolution, see the marching cubes method.

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately, cubic honeycomb does't work for 2:1 isosceles

Comment: A square can be split in two 1:1:sqrt(2) triangles.

Comment: Alternately, you can use the alternated cubic honeycomb = octahedron-tetrahedron tiling.

Comment: Hm... there isn't a space filling tesselation with tiles having non-regular-polygonal sides, right? :-/

Comment: Any [parallelepiped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) will tile the space.

Comment: But there is no parallelpiped whose sides can be put together of 2:1 isosceles, each ^^ EDIT: Oh, i guess I'm wrong here. Found a such.

Comment: Why do you need 2:2:1, anyways?

Comment: No more answers guys?

Answer (score 1):

In freeform shapes tiling is achieved via a very complicated algorithm. In real world architecture there is this method of tiling with as many identical tiles as possible and still get the shape, but there are angle tolerances and all sort of tolerances that you can manipulate. check paneling of freeform shapes.

Comment: Do you have any useful source for that? I always get search results that do not really fit my needs...

Comment: I always get search results that do not really fit my needs... I have nearly no freedom in the triangle shape and i want to minimize difference in the normals and the number of "torsion points" (as they are called in the papers i found so far)